# Routing m:n-relations in EF-Core and oData using ASP.NET-Core mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core, odata

I am currently trying to migrate an ASP.NET-mvc web-application to ASP.NET Core. Today i faced a big problem working with the EntityFramework-Core and using oData to route the data.

The problem is that the Core-version of the EntityFramework generates bridge entities (like in the actual DB) to handle m:n-relations, while the old version handled this differently. Now if i try to use an oData $expand to access the entity (n) from the other entity (m), I get an empty result.

https://blog.oneunicorn.com/2017/09/25/many-to-many-relationships-in-ef-core-2-0-part-4-a-more-general-abstraction/

I tried using this example, but did not get any results either.

*Old way of handling m:n:*

```
modelBuilder.Entity<App>()
    .HasMany(e => e.News)
    .WithMany(e => e.Apps)
    .Map(m => m.ToTable("Apps_News").MapLeftKey("AppId").MapRightKey("NewsId"));
```

*Core way:*

```
modelBuilder.Entity<AppsNews>(entity =>
{
    entity.HasKey(e => new { e.AppId, e.NewsId })
        .HasName("PK_dbo.Apps_News");

    ...

    entity.HasOne(d => d.News)
        .WithMany(p => p.AppsNews)
        .HasForeignKey(d => d.NewsId)
        .HasConstraintName("FK_dbo.Apps_News_dbo.News_NewsId");

    entity.HasOne(d => d.App)
        .WithMany(p => p.AppsNews)
        .HasForeignKey(d => d.AppId)
        .HasConstraintName("FK_dbo.Apps_News_dbo.Apps_AppId");
});
```

The odata/$metadata Shows this for the EntitySets:

```
<EntitySet Name="Apps" EntityType="App">
<NavigationPropertyBinding Path="App" Target="Apps"/>
<NavigationPropertyBinding Path="News" Target="News"/>
<NavigationPropertyBinding Path="AppsNews/News" Target="News"/>
<NavigationPropertyBinding Path="AppsNews/App" Target="Apps"/>
</EntitySet>
```

An oData $batch-request like this: `odata/News?$expand=Apps` returns following:

```
"Id": "123",
"Text": test,
"Title": "test",
"Apps": []
```

Maybe anyone faced this problem before? I am thankful for any recomandations. If more code or Information is needed please simply contact me. Thank you in advance :).